# admin/dashboard a defind route not operating

Tags: php, laravel

I have started programming after two years and switched from zendframework2 to laravel. i am following a youtube tutorial which is made in the earlier version of laravel. i have defined a simple route in web.php

which gives me a working url of **admin/dashboard**

i have been using it in this project until i used it in my slider.blade.php

the route admin/dashboard works with Request::is but does not work with href route. i get an error of admin/dashboard is not defined. but it is defined in web.php and also in php artisan route:list as admin/dashboard. i have also tried to define admin/dashboard outside Route::group in web.php and using admin.dashboard but i can't get out of this.
it might be

Html:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('admin/dashboard*')? 'active':''}} ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('admin/dashboard')}}"> <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i> <p>Dashboard</p> </a> 
</li>
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () { 
    Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index'])->name('admin.dashboard'); 
});
```

**web.php**:

```
    <?php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Auth::routes();


    //beneath is the route that can work both for auth and non auth for admin/
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {


        Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
            Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index'])->name('admin.dashboard');
            Route::resource('slider', 'Admin\SliderController');
        });

    });
```

Comment: <li class="{{ Request::is('admin/dashboard*')? 'active':''}} ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('admin/dashboard')}}">
          <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
          <p>Dashboard</p>
        </a>
      </li>

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index'])->name('admin.dashboard');
        
    });

Comment: stackoverflow did not let me add code to the question so i had to add it here, sorry

Comment: Can you add your web.php file code here?

Comment: Seeker, click [edit] to edit your question and add the code that you put into the comments.

Comment: @Seeker, what do you mean by **did not let** you? your `routes/web.php` file will be enough to troubleshoot your problem

Comment: @udo E, robin has edited my question, the route group is in web.php. will it do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/admin/dashboard">
```

only troubleshoots your routing problem but doesn't solve it.

If you follow the above link and it gets you the correct view without Laravel throwing any errors then you are one step 
close to solving the route issue. It means there is a route with that **front-end** name. However, from my explanation below you find out that the **server-side** name is **admin.dashboardadmin.dashboard**.

So, let's go about solving the problem.

The `as` key does not replace your route name, it combines them. So, only use one of the methods - the `as` key or the `->name()` method in the inner route definition.

I'm testing this with my own machine on Laravel 5.8 and can confirm that you can use both as in your code. However, the name for the route in your code is - **admin.dashboardadmin.dashboard**  - surprisingly.

Either of the route definitions below should solve the problem:

```
//beneath is the route that can work both for auth and non auth for admin/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

        Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index']);

        Route::resource('slider', 'Admin\SliderController');
    });

});
```

**OR**

```
//beneath is the route that can work both for auth and non auth for admin/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

        Route::get('dashboard', ['uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index'])->name('dashboard');

        Route::resource('slider', 'Admin\SliderController');
    });

});
```

Either ways, the generated front-end link should be

```
admin/dashboard
```

And the server-side route to access the link is

```
route('admin.dashboard')
```

The html should be:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('admin/dashboard*')? 'active':''}} ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('admin.dashboard')}}">
        <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i> 
        <p>Dashboard</p> 
    </a> 
</li>
```

**Note**: do not test generated route links by putting them directly into the browser address bar. Put them in a link `href`, the browser will resolve them either absolutely or relatively - depending on the link type.

Comment: But it's a different route than the route in the question.

Comment: The `as` key in the route can be removed as well. Then you can use the `->name('admin.dashboard')` method to give you **route('admin.dashboard')** as valid route.  I just wanted to show the right way of using the`as` key in a route definition.

Comment: sir UdoE, you have done great job with amazing answer, not only you provided a detailed solution, you also highlighted the conceptual difficulties and provided their solution too. i have checked every thing you mentioned in this answer. 1) with my old code, my route is admin.dashboardadmin.dashboard and is working too. 2) using only 'as' solves the problem 3) using only name->solves the problem. now i only use this route in my route in sidebar.blade.php href="{{route('admin.dashboard')}}" i also tried with admin/dashboard but that is still returning 'not defined' with 'as' or 'name'.

Comment: i still wonder, how can i use admin/dashboard in Request:: but can't use admin/dashboard in route()

Comment: @Seeker, I'm glad you understand the problem better and can get around it. Usually, that first parameter you provide to `Route::get()` can serve two purposes. It can just be the front-end display name of your route if the associated controller method returns a `view` or it can be an actual relative part to the view if no view is returned by your controller. I think  the static Request:: call is using the front-end display link and not the actual route

Comment: @Seeker, does this method `DashboardController@index` return a `view`?

Comment: yes sir, DashboardController@index does return a view. return view('admin.dashboard')

Comment: That clarifies the issue with `Request::is($path)`. It takes a reachable path parameter and not just the display link used in your route definition.  The relative path `admin/dashboard` is where `view('admin.dashboard')` is pointing to, so it returns true.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a "/" before routes in "href" for internal links in Laravel. and basically you don't need to call "route" method in "href" because Laravel automatically determine which route it's. try this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/admin/dashboard">
```

Comment: thank you sir, this was the only combination i didn't try out but it also give error of Route [/admin/dashboard] not defined.

Comment: try this out too: <a class="nav-link" href="/admin/dashboard">

Comment: thank you sir, it worked like a charm. please update your answer for this is the correct answer. can you please mention how it worked without using route, since it is working with route too but with another controller.

Comment: i am thankful again sir, do you know how it worked without using route, if you would also mention it in the answer, it will help other people that visit this answer

Comment: @Seeker, if you can't get the link with the route helper `route('admin.dashboard')`, there is still a problem with your `web.php` file.

Comment: As I said in my answer, Laravel automatically determine which route it goes to. so the route method is not necessary. the route method is more used in the controller.

Comment: sir Udo E. i have updated my question with web.php. please have a look. also to mention that <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('admin.slider.index')}}"> is in same blade file and is working without any problem

Answer (score 0):

The route helper accepts the name of a route, try this:

```
href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route

Comment: sir i tried it already, but it does not work, Route [admin.dashboard] not defined

Comment: it's because of this part: ```['as' => 'dasboard']``` which is prefixing all route names inside the group with dashboard. So you're route name is now ```dashboardadmin.dashboard```.

Comment: thank you for your time sir, i tried with this solution just to get better understanding but i got Route [dashboardadmin.dashboard] not defined

Answer (score 0):

The route that you define:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () { 
Route::get('dashboard', [
        'as' => 'dashboard', 
        'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index'
    ])->name('admin.dashboard'); 
});
```

produce `/dashboard` link and `route('admin.dashboard')` named route which both are not being used. The solution is can be either using `/dashboard` as link and `route('admin.dashboard')` for named route as below:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('/dashboard')? 'active':''}} ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('admin.dashboard')}}">
        <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i> <p>Dashboard</p>
    </a> 
</li>
```

assuming your group route have no prefix.

Comment: oh yes sir, my routes are in group in web.php

Comment: oh sorry I mean prefix, so how is it? is it working now?